# How should I spread the load on a Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

We have software that points to thousands of business objects, and at regular intervals we want to call a method, `Calc` on each of these objects, which can take up to ten seconds to run.  We have a Web Method in a .asmx file called `CalcAll`, which iterates through each of these objects calling the `Calc` method.  This WebMethod is single-threaded, and we want to boost performance by spreading the load for calling the `Calc` method across multiple requests and even multiple servers.

Can I safely create a Web Reference back to the same Web Service and call a new Web Method `Calc` thousands of times from the `CalcAll` web method?  Won't the later calls time out?  I could throttle the calls, but I don't know how many servers might be processing these web method calls, so I'm not quite sure what the upper limit for currently active requests should be, and if we are running with an Amazon Auto-scaling Group, there might not be a practical upper limit.  What is the best technique for spreading the load for a web method call across multiple requests/servers?

Comment: What you are looking is "load balancer" and can be done with hardware. You could [read up](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/) how stackoverflow does it.

Comment: I will read the document, but I am already familiar with Load Balancing.  Many of our customers install our product locally with a limited numbers of servers (often two).  Will later requests time out as the limited number of servers are unable to process the requests in a timely fashion?